# Is it possible to provide an implicit way of converting object into string for angular templates?

Tags: angularjs

Let's assume I've got a few objects that have the same prototype and I want to customize their display in Angular template. I know I can create my own filter, and then use it like that:

```
<p>{{anObjectOfProtoP | myCustomFilter}}</p>
```

or a function attached to $scope:

```
<p>{{myCustomFunction(anotherObjectOfProtoP)}}</p>
```

My question is: is it possible to achieve similar functionality without explicitly specifying the rendering function every time? The ideal solution would be if angular checked for function `toAngularString` on object inside the `{{}}`, and then used it's return value in template.
In other words, I'd like Angular to do

```
function (o) {
   if (typeof o.toAngularString === 'function') return o.toAngularString();
   return o;
}
```

on every object inside `{{}}`.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on whether you use `{{ ... }}` or `ng-bind` syntax, the `.toJSON` and the `.toString` function on your object will be called to determine its representation. Hence, you can provide the representation you want in either `.toString` or `.toJSON` function of your object.

This discrepancy in which function is called has let to [some problems](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/764), actually.

Another way you can do that is by writing your own directive `my-toangularstr` as this:

```js
app.directive('myToangularstr', function () {
  return {
    scope: true,
    template: '<span class="my-angular-value">{{ val.toAngularString() }}</span>',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs['myToangularstr'], function (newVal) {
        if (typeof newVal !== 'undefined') {
          scope.val = newVal;
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

A working demo showing all three methods is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PyXZvk).

I think that is as close as one can get using the external API of angular.