# Difference between ng-bind and interpolation {{}} in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Is there any difference between 
{{ }} and ng-bind in angular.

I am quite new to Angular. I started with using {{ }} and then in the documentation i find ng-bind. I think they do the same work but then why an extra directive, if not then please tell the difference.

Comment: Voted to reopen as it is a clear question, however this question can get an answer from [why ng-bind is better than `{{}}` in angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)

Comment: I think Grijesh is right -- this looks like the same question (and this question a dupe): [AngularJS : Why ng-bind is better than {{}} in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is some hint in the official docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

> Typically, you don't use ngBind directly, but instead you use the
>   double curly markup like {{ expression }} which is similar but less
>   verbose.
>
> It is preferable to use ngBind instead of {{ expression }} if a
>   template is momentarily displayed by the browser in its raw state
>   before Angular compiles it. Since ngBind is an element attribute, it
>   makes the bindings invisible to the user while the page is loading.

Answer (score 10):

The most obvious difference between them is Flash of Unstyled content while using `{{ ... }}`.

However, there is a more subtle difference between the two if the object you pass to `{{ obj }}` and `ng-bind="obj"` is **not a string**.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/19744728/987185 :

> Depending on whether you use `{{ ... }}` or `ng-bind` syntax, the
>   `.toJSON` and the `.toString` function on your object will be called
>   to determine its representation.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the above mentioned answers,

Performance Issues with Interpolation:

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)   thread better,

`ng-bind` is a directive and will place a watcher on the passed variable. So the `ng-bind` will only apply when the passed value does actually change.

The brackets on the other hand will be dirty checked and refreshed in every $digest, even if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 8):

{{ }} can flash when the page is loading, ng-bind hides the expression properly until it is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

In AngularJs ng-bind directive works as alternative to the interpolation directive {{ }}. By inserting an ng-bind attribute to  HTML element we can insert AngularJS data into it.

Here is an example:

```
 <div ng-controller="DemoController" >
  <span ng-bind="demoData.doThis()"></span>
</div>
```

The Key Difference is ng-bind attribute wont show  Html content on page loading, where as interpolation Directive show as flash of content without style while page loading.

Answer (score 3):

Another difference is the way `ng-bind` and `interpolation` display the data.
`ng-bind` calls the `toString()` method, whereas `interpolation` uses a custom "stringify" function.

## Example

```
<div ng-controller="showClockCtrl">
    <p>The current time is {{currentDateTime}}.</p>
    <p>The current time is <span ng-bind="currentDateTime"></span>.</p>
</div>

<div ng-controller="showClockCtrl">
    <p>MyObject is {{myObject}}</p>
    <p>MyObject is <span ng-bind="myObject"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var showClockCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.currentDateTime = new Date();
    $scope.myObject = {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2',
        'key3': 'value3'
    }
};
</script>
```

## Output

```
The current time is "2017-11-18T15:09:59.429Z".

The current time is Sat Nov 18 2017 10:09:59 GMT-0500 (EST).

MyObject is {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}

MyObject is [object Object]
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when we  load our application in the browser , we can notice flashing content for some milliseconds before {{ name }} is resolved and data is loaded.

This happens because the template is loaded before AngularJS had a chance to go in and compile the elements. To resolve this issue, you can use ng-cloak directive.

In the first approach(i.e. {{}}), AngularJS evaluates the expression then replaces it with some value which sometime be left with the flashing double curly brackets but ng-bind saves this time by informing AngularJS to put the contents of the expression within the element itself.

Note:
{{}} sometimes cause performance issue if we have thousand of bindings in our page.In these scenario's, we should go with ng-bind.

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation is only used for a Read-only purpose and you cannot assign a value to inside the mustache bracket to a variable that has been declared inside the Typescript file.

The basic difference between them is that ng-bind should always be used inside the element <> but Interpolation directive can be used inside, outside and between the elements.

Answer (score -2):

Not an answer, but ng-bind is easily exchangable by ng-bind-html, which puts actual html text inside the element instead of pure text.

Since I was wondering for (ok, just) minutes, I add it here as well. My problem was, text-DOM explorer shows the same output.