# Difference between two angular js bindings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've two codes in my HTML structure.

First one is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app>
  <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <p>{{name}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and another is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app>
  <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <p ng-bind="name"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Both are giving the same output then, where the difference lies?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using

```
<p>{{name}}</p>
```

While  angularjs is loading, you might see your brackets on  the page. You can use ng-cloak to avoid the user to see the {{name}}.

Its better to use

```
<p ng-bind="name"></p>
```

As this removes the problem. the ng-bind will show the value,only when the  value  is changed.
There are so many explanations for the difference you can check

[AngularJS : Why ng-bind is better than {{}} in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)

[Difference between ng-bind and interpolation {{}} in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741586/difference-between-ng-bind-and-interpolation-in-angular?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

> The similarity between this two is
>
> - Used for one way binding.
> - they are used to bind variables on data on view.

**Interpolation Directive**

This uses `{{}}` inside that you can have an expression with scope variables which are placed in respective scope..

**ng-bind**

Sometimes angular shows `{{}}` while rendering a page which is un-compiled angular content, `ng-bind` does avoid that. By using this you need use to add using `ng-cloak` directive.

Comment: does it helped you??