# Why is ng-bind and {{}} giving different outputs for a json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interpolation

Here is the code that I am using, don't understand why is there a difference in the output of `ng-bind` and `{{}}`.

```js
angular.module('Test', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="Test">
  <input type="text" ng-model="foo.bar" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="foo.baz" />
  <p ng-bind="foo"></p>
  <p>{{ foo }}</p>
</div>
```

This is the output that I am getting

```
//for ng-bind
[object Object]      

//for {{}}
{"foo":"ankur","bar":"23"}
```

Comment: The reason this is happening is because you are sending an array of objects from the controller to your view.

And then you directly bind the array to a <p> tag. So the entire array is getting displayed with object as it is unparsed on your view..

Comment: No, you are wrong. How can you say I am using array of objects ?

Comment: @Francescoes. Where are you seeing an *array*? `[object Object]` is the standard `toString` value, not an array.

Comment: @deceze right, my fault, it is also the string value of an object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741586/difference-between-ng-bind-and-interpolation-in-angular   look at this..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that the `{{}}` is evaluating the expression before to bind it to the view, while `ng-bind` is not doing that, so you are having a string rapresentation of your <s>array</s> object.

Comment: ok, but i thought both {{}} and ng-bind are meant for the same thing. aren't they ?

Comment: they are, they just work differently, so it all depends on what you need and how you need it to work. It would have been redundant if both were doing the exact same thing, there are use cases where you need one over another.

Comment: they are not exactly the same thing. Here the source code of [ngBind](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L3)