# Can anyone explain the difference between ng-bind and expressions in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have found the below definition about the difference

> Typically, you don't use ngBind directly, but instead you use the double curly markup like {{ expression }} which is similar but less verbose.
>
> It is preferable to use ngBind instead of {{ expression }} if a template is momentarily displayed by the browser in its raw state before AngularJS compiles it. Since ngBind is an element attribute, it makes the bindings invisible to the user while the page is loading.

but i didn't get this properly.

Can anyone explain in simple language with Example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ngBind` is an attribute. Until your JS files are being loaded and interpreted, that attribute will not be "taken" into consideration, so no `HTML artifacts` will be displayed.

`{{ expression }}` instead, is immediately shown as inner HTML on page load, which creates annoying flickers. HTML inner content is briefly displayed in its uncompiled state while your application is loading (all your JS files that get loaded and interpreted). `ngCloak` is recommended to be used with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741586/difference-between-ng-bind-and-interpolation-in-angular

Comment: also, `ngBind` is recommended to be used when you have syntax conflicts with other languages

Comment: Perhaps elaborate as to _why_ [`ngCloak`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak) is recommended and _what it does_ for the OP, or at least give a reference to the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak) for it

Comment: Good point @cnorthfield! Was written in hurry. Thanks!