# AngularJS Expression Output Object String Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I'm using a class (acting more like a kind of struct) representing a string value, with the side-effect that it changes its value every time you access it:

```
function Foo() {

    var value = 'a';

    this.getValue = function() {

        if (value == 'a') {

            value = 'b';
            return 'a';

        }
        else {

            value = 'a';
            return 'b';

        }

    }

}
```

..and I override it's `toString()` method:

```
Foo.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.getValue();
}
```

Outputting this value is fine with a direct reference:

```
var foo = new Foo();

alert(foo); //a
document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = foo; //b
```

However, outputting the object with an AngularJS expression results in `{}` being displayed rather than the `toString()`/`getValue()` value:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var app = angular.module('main', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.val = foo;
    alert($scope.val); //a (has not been changed by previous line)

});
```

..and then:

```
<div ng-app="main" ng-controller="ctrl">{{val}}</div> //{} (rather than b)
```

I could just use `$scope.val = foo.getValue();`, `$scope.val = foo.toString();` or even `$scope.val = foo + '';`, and according to [Is it possible to provide an implicit way of converting object into string for angular templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744610/is-it-possible-to-provide-an-implicit-way-of-converting-object-into-string-for-a) `ng-bind` calls the `toString()` method, but why is it not called when Angular evaluates the object in an expression?